# Include JavaScript into JSP without encoding problems

Tags: javascript, jsp, encoding, utf-8

I'm with a very strange problem.

All my application it's configured with UTF-8. All files (checked with "iconv"), all headers, charsets, pageEncodings, struts.properties, velocity.properties... everything it's defined as UTF-8. My tomcat start with `"-Dfile.encoding=UTF8"` attribute and `<connector>` (in server.xml) it's defined with `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` attribute.

But when I use `<%@ include file="myfile.js" %>` to import a JavaScript into my JSP, all characters with accent are displayed as "Ã£".

I noticed that if I paste the JS code direct into the JSP, everything goes alright. But unfortunately, I need to use it with `<%@include/>`.

May anyone help me, please? If you need more information, please let me know.

Comment: Why not use a <script> tag and allow it all to happen on the client?

Comment: @Diodeus It's an old system with a lot of JS files inside WEB-INF folder. So the JS isn't visible as an URL to be imported like this.
The problem started when I converted all the project to UTF-8. Before it was a mess (UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 and CP-1252), but this kind of JS was ok, without encoding problems.

Comment: Create a servlet which `doGet` method receives the JavaScript file name as parameter (in query string) and will handle a response of type `text/javascript` where you will seek for the desired JavaScript file in your WEB-INF/`<js-files-location>`/js-file.js and place its content into the current response.